# Retrieving data and inserting to database

Tags: java, html, sql, jsp

In the picture in below, when user press submit button, application inserting choosen number to to database. But it does not work for activityid number. After pressing submit button, activityid is returning null and buy is returning choosen number. How can I do insert correct activityid on database  [image]

music.jsp

```
  <table border="1" width="30%" height="30%">
            <th><font color='#D18603'>ActivityID</font>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Type</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Description</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>City</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Location</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Date</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Price</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Buy</font>

                        <%
                            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
                            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/users", "users", "123");

                            Statement st = con.createStatement();
                            ResultSet rs;
                            rs = st.executeQuery("select * from activities where type='müzik'");
                            while (rs.next()) {

                                out.println("<tr>");
                                out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("id")+"</td>");
                                out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("type")+ "</td>");
                                out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("description")+ "</td>");
                                out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("city") + "</td>");
                                out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("location")+ "</td>");
                                out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("date") + "</td>");
                                out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("price") + "</td>");
                                out.println("<td><b><form action='reservations.jsp'><select name='buy'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form></b>");
                                out.println("</tr>");

                            }
                            st.close();

                        %>
```

Reservation.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%

String username = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("username");
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/users", "users", "123");

String sorgu = "INSERT INTO reservation(id,username,buy) VALUES ('" + request.getParameter("id") + "', '" + username + "','" + request.getParameter("buy") + "') ";

java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();

int rowNum = st.executeUpdate(sorgu);
response.sendRedirect("paypal.html");
st.close();
%>
```

Comment: I don't see where you've assigned a name to the ActivityId column to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: yes. This is the problem. How can i do that ? I searched on the google but icannot find. This is my solution can you help me ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the  tag around all data in each row, and add (hidden) form tags to each column so that all the data gets included in the form submission. For the sake of clarity, I've eliminated everything but how to organize the form tags and how to include the "id" in the form submission

```
                        rs = st.executeQuery("select * from activities where type='müzik'");
                        while (rs.next()) {

                            out.println("<tr>");
                            out.println("<form action='reservations.jsp'>");
                            out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("id") + "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + td.getString("id")+"'></td>");
                            out.println("<td><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form></b></td>");
                            out.println("</td></tr>");

                        }
                        st.close();
```

Comment: i did what you said, but it returns still null for activity id in database

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add "name='id'" to the input field. I have corrected my answer. But is the problem that the value is not available from the parameters submitted to the db insert jsp page, or with data in the database? It's with the parameters, right?